# Spring Social Twitter stream returns HTTP 401 unauthorized

Tags: spring, twitter, spring-boot, spring-social, spring-social-twitter

I try to make a stream connection to Twitter using spring-social-twitter, but when I try to make a request I've got `401 unauthorized`.

spring-social-twitter is trying to connect to https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json. When I debug it and try to get `response.getBody()` I've got `HttpRetryException` with detailed message: `cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode`.

I have proper authorization for app but I have no authorization for access token, since I don't need it here. I use `1.1.0.RELEASE` version.

I will be very glad for your help!

This is my call for stream:

```
final Stream stream = twitter.streamingOperations().filter(keywords, listeners);
```

This is my simple listener class:

```
private class TwitterStreamListener implements StreamListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TwitterStreamListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onTweet(Tweet tweet) {
        LOGGER.info("onTweet");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDelete(StreamDeleteEvent deleteEvent) {
        LOGGER.info("onDelete");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLimit(int numberOfLimitedTweets) {
        LOGGER.info("onLimit");
    }

    @Override
    public void onWarning(StreamWarningEvent warningEvent) {
        LOGGER.info("onWarning");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer. I posted it here, so maybe it will help others with the same issue.

I figured out that Twitter blocked my app to make a streaming connection before I connect myself, as a browser client to the app. So I needed to received access token of a user to make a stream connection.

Earlier when I tried to connect - nothing happened.. It was because I had wrong Callback URL in my app settings (on twitter's page).

When I changed Callback URL to `http://127.0.0.1` (it could be any kind of valid URL and your application doesn't need to have the same, but you can't use something like `localhost`).

After that  I could connect my app to my twitter's account which allows me to start streaming connection. After all I don't know why Twitter requires user connection for stream public tweets. It is not required for search REST API.